# Amazon Emr: Unable to increase default memory settings

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, heap-memory, amazon-emr

I am running a spark job (spark-submit) and facing `outOfMemory` and `open files` memory issues a lot. I am searching all over couldn't find anything helpful.

Can somebody help me increase the amazon emr default memory settings?

```
[hadoop@ip-10-0-52-76 emr]$ ulimit -a
core file size          (blocks, -c) 0
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
scheduling priority             (-e) 0
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
pending signals                 (-i) 31862
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 64
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 1024
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200
real-time priority              (-r) 0
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 8192
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 31862
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
file locks                      (-x) unlimited
```

Increasing the java heap size and open files size will resolve my issue.

For more information, I am using `r3.4xlarge` emr clusters. Thanks

Comment: you got memory error when you run the spark script.?

Comment: Hi @sahildesai I am getting these errors while running spark-submit, it's a spark application

Comment: yes so most probably you have to increase driver memory.

Comment: go to spark home/conf/ spark-default filw and set the driver memory

Answer (score 0):

In EMR you can change the memory setting in **/etc/spark/conf/spark-defaults.conf** file.

If tasks are getting outofmemory means, you should increase your executor memory. Please choose the executor memory based on data size.

**spark.executor.memory            5120M**

Incase, driver throws outofmemory error, you can increase the driver memory.

**spark.driver.memory              5120M**

Comment: If you are still facing error, please update the error stack trace. So that will help you in better way.